# Am not able to launch edgedriver browser by configuring in feature file karate framework

Tags: karate

- configure driver = { type:  'msedgedriver' } and driver 'https://github.com'
  the same works when i use chrome

Command error cannot run program msedgedriver create process error 2 the system cannot find the file specified

Am expecting edge browser should launch with the address provided

Comment: sounds like you have to provide the path to the executable and ensure it is installed. refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#configure-driver

Comment: Thanks Peter now am able launch edgedriver missing executable: in the configure driver and version mismatch (msedgedriver and edge version)

Comment: @PeterThomas now again its not launching msedge browser

Answer (score 1):

*Configure driver = { type: 'msedgedriver' ,executable: 'path of your driver' webDriverSession: { capabilities: { browserName: 'edge' }}}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).